# Замена символа в html

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в тексте заменить `\` на `&#x` ? То есть, чтобы при добавлении кода FA, например, `\f042`, в итоге в html было `&#xf042`. Замена нужна только для одного класса (внутри одного div).

P.S. вопрос решил, но через CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря задача полностью не ясна, но этот вариант может быть частью решения.

```js
let text = '\\f042'
console.log(text)
text = text.replace(/\\/, '&#x')
console.log(text)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Данный значок FA просто для примера указан, а значки будут разные. Правда, сделал по-другому и без JS (вроде работает без ошибок).

Comment: @Plutooo а как именно реализовали если не секрет?

Comment: deasmont, там в :after это делалось, а текст писался в html. Добавил тот же текст в content, в after, и можно писать просто со слеш, и шрифт FA нормально показывается.

Comment: @Plutooo лучше это решение вынести куда-нибудь возможно в конец вопроса или в новый ответ